# Задача покер Python

Tags: python, файлы

Есть входной файл где записаны значения пяти карт, нужно чтобы по этим картам выдавалась комбинация, и вроде как с подсказками удалось написать код, но когда пытаюсь сделать инкремент 2 списка, выдает ошибку list index out of range, думаю, что в принципе подобного нельзя делать в питоне, поэтому и задаю вопрос, можно ли как-то исправить эту ошибку или надо полностью переписывать код как-то по другому?

```
a = []
file = open('input.txt','r')
a = file.readline().split()
b = []
a.sort()
li = len(a) - 2
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    b[int(a[i]) - 1] += 1
    i += 1
if len(b) - 1 == 5:
    print("Impossible")
elif b[len(b)-1] == 4:
    print("Four of a kind")
elif b[len(b) - 2] == 3:
    while li >= 0:
        if b[li] == 2:
            print ("Full house")
            li -= 1
            break
        else:
            print("Three of a kind")
            li -= 1
            break
elif b[len(b) - 1] == 2:
    while li >= 0:
        if b[li] == 2:
            print("Two pairs")
            li -= 1
            break
        else:
            print("One pair")
            li -= 1
            break
else:
    for i in range(1,len(a)):
        if a[i] - 1 != a[i-1]:
            print ("Nothing")
            i += 1
            break
    print ("Straight")
```

Comment: Тяжко читать неоптимальный некомментированный код. Как и догадываться, что такое "инкремент 2 списка" в нём, если строка не указана. Но список в Python, конечно, можно увеличивать, вопрос, как и зачем. Почитайте "методы списков". Например, тут - первые же три метода: <https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/ispolzovanie-spiskov-list-python/>. Вы, наверное, не инкремент списка делаете, а за его границы вылезаете.

Comment: В 8 строке выдается ошибка

Comment: Тогда точно читайте ту ссылку, что я дал. Если вы в строке 8 пытаетесь так список расширить, то там написан правильный способ, как это сделать. Почитайте заодно, как цикл `for` работает, он у вас тоже работать будет неправильно с учётом строк его цикла. И про срезы почитайте - код станет, как минимум, почитабельнее.